# Fill dates column with next date from previous date in row

Tags: r, date, dataframe, dplyr, zoo

I have to fill a date column in a dataframe adding one day to last date and then to the end (adding one day). it's not filling missing dates because from the last date there is no more dates, so there's no gaps.

There's more columns but let's keep it simple for the sake of the example.

```
df <- structure(list(dates = c("1991-01-01", "1991-01-02", "1991-01-03", 
NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  dates     
* <chr>     
1 1991-01-01
2 1991-01-02
3 1991-01-03
4 NA        
5 NA        
6 NA
```

I know I can fill it replacing with a sequence (seq.Date) but I think some time ago I've read somewhere an elegant function for filling a vector using last date and a lag.

expected result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  dates     
* <chr>     
1 1991-01-01
2 1991-01-02
3 1991-01-03
4 1991-01-04   
5 1991-01-05        
6 1991-01-06
```

something similar to `zoo::na.locf()` but for dates taking into account I don't know "from" and "to" beforehand

any hint?

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(dates = as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
 fill(dates) %>%
 mutate(dates = if_else(duplicated(dates), 
                        dates + cumsum(duplicated(dates)), 
                        dates))

  dates     
  <date>    
1 1991-01-01
2 1991-01-02
3 1991-01-03
4 1991-01-04
5 1991-01-05
6 1991-01-06
```

Or a possibility involving just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(dates = as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
        dates = if_else(is.na(dates),
                        last(na.omit(dates)) + cumsum(is.na(dates)),
                        dates))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try to `fill` the missing dates with previous value and add `cumsum` of `NA` values to it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(temp = +(is.na(dates)), 
        dates = as.Date(dates)) %>% 
  tidyr::fill(dates) %>%
  mutate(dates_new = dates + cumsum(temp)) %>%
  select(-temp)

#   dates      dates_new 
#  <date>     <date>    
#1 1991-01-01 1991-01-01
#2 1991-01-02 1991-01-02
#3 1991-01-03 1991-01-03
#4 1991-01-03 1991-01-04
#5 1991-01-03 1991-01-05
#6 1991-01-03 1991-01-06
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R idea,

```
as.Date(max(df$dates, na.rm = TRUE)) + seq(sum(is.na(df$dates)))
#[1] "1991-01-04" "1991-01-05" "1991-01-06"
```

Or assign them back to your data frame, i.e.

```
df$dates[is.na(df$dates)] <- as.character(as.Date(max(df$dates, na.rm = TRUE)) + seq(sum(is.na(df$dates))))

df
#1 1991-01-01
#2 1991-01-02
#3 1991-01-03
#4 1991-01-04
#5 1991-01-05
#6 1991-01-06
```